# Slideshow should play on a click event

Tags: jquery, slideshow, autoplay, jmpress

I have used [slideshow with jmpress.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/05/slideshow-with-jmpress-js/)

Where I have used a jquery which autoplay by setting it true or false but I want it to start by clicking a link on a first slide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var jmpressOpts = {
            animation       : { transitionDuration : '1.8s' }
        };

        $( '#jms-slideshow' ).jmslideshow( $.extend( true, { jmpressOpts : jmpressOpts }, {
            autoplay    : true,
            bgColorSpeed: '1.8s',
            arrows      : false
        }));

    });
</script>
```

Does any one know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems see if this helps. 
https://github.com/jmpressjs/jmpress.js/issues/131